# Linear Algebra inequality with eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I am stuck in a proof:

$A$ is a symmetric positive deﬁnite matrix, and $B$ is a symmetric matrix such that $||B|| ≤ ||A^{-1}||^{−1}$.

Let $B = \Psi L \Psi^T$ be the eigenvalue decomposition of matrix $B$. Remove columns of $\Psi$ that are eigenvectors of value $0$, so $L$ only contains nonsingular terms. Let $v$ be the eigenvector corresponding to the largest absolute eigenvalue of $(L^{-1} + \Psi^T A^{-1} \Psi)^{-1}$.

Then  $|v^T (L^{-1} + \Psi^T A^{-1} \Psi) v| \geq |v^T L^{-1} v| − |v^T \Psi^T A^{-1} \Psi v| \geq ||L||^{−1} − ||A^{−1}||.$

How to obtain the last inequality? I am also not sure if all the information I have given before is required. Thanks a lot!

---

I have edited this post. My original question was how to obtain the first inequality but now, I am stuck again. Thanks in advance for helping out again!

Answer (score 1):

$|x+y|\geq |x|-|y|$ because $|x|=|(x+y)-y| \leq |x+y|+|y|$.

Take $y=v^T (\Psi^T A^{-1} \Psi) v$ and $x=v^T (L^{-1}v)$.